# Reseting React nested Navigators within render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Context: building a React Native mobile application. Along the bottom of the UI are four tabs. Three contain simple `StackNavigator`s to preserve navigation state within that tab. The fourth screen is itself a tab navigator. The `screen` of each sub-tab is a `StackNavigator` to preserve their own navigation history while within the tab.

Outline:

The top level navigator:

```
BottomTabNavigator
|_Tab 1 (StackNavigator) (initial route)
|_Tab 2 (StackNavigator)
|_Tab 3 (StackNavigator)
|_Tab 4 (Tab4Container)
```

The sub-navigator:

```
Tab4Navigator (MaterialTopTabNavigator)
  |_Subtab 1 (StackNavigator) (initial route)
    |_Screen 4.1.1 (initial route)
    |_Screen 4.1.2
  |_Subtab 2 (StackNavigator) (initial route)
    |_Screen 4.2.1 (initial route)
    |_Screen 4.2.2
```

Tab 4 has a few components above the tabs themselves, so that's wrapped in a container. Essentially:

```
class Tab4Container extends React.router {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Header />
        <Tab4Navigator navigation={this.props.navigation}>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Issue: The nested tab navigator doesn't reset its state when the user leaves Tab4 and comes back. First, the user clicks to Tab4, then Subtab 2, then Screen 4.2.2. Then the user clicks on Tab 2. Then the user returns to Tab 4. The current screen should be 4.1.1 but it is still 4.2.2.

Tab4Navigator is structured:

```
const Tab4Navigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    subTab1: createStackNavigator(
      {
        screen_4_1_1: {
          screen: Screen411Container
        },
        screen_4_1_2: {
          screen: Screen412Container
        },
      },
      { initialRouteName: "screen_4_2_1" }
    ),
    subTab2: createStackNavigator(
      {
        screen_4_2_1: {
          screen: Screen421Container
        },
        screen_4_2_2: {
          screen: Screen422Container
        },
      },
      { initialRouteName: "screen_4_2_1" }
    ),
  },
  { initialRouteName: "subTab1" }
)
```

Question: How can I reset the StackNavigator when the Tab4Navigator is re-rendered?

Comment: This is how stacknavigator works and it keeps the state of the stack until you reset it.

Comment: @prabhat Yes that's the case. I'm asking how to reset the state when the tab is re-rendered. I'll add that explicitly to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add tabBarOnPress event on Tab4Navigator and then [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset) stack . Check this [GitHub](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1557) link also

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

......

{ initialRouteName: "subTab1", tabBarOnPress: this.handleTabPress }

handleTabPress = ({ navigation }) => {
  navigation.popToTop();
  navigation.navigate(navigation.state.routeName);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this on both the top level `createBottomTabNavigator` and the nested `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` but neither seem to fire. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Nevermind, it needed to be in the navigation options not the configuration for the navigator. Thank you!